# Import .pfx Certificate with Keytool is not working

Tags: ssl, elasticsearch, keytool

Right now I am securing my installation of ElasticSearch using SSL.
In the guide they mention to secure the endpoint by importing an x.509 certificate using the following keytool command:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore node01.jks -file cacert.pem -alias my_ca
```

The problem is that I have a .pfx file generated by a CA authority. If I pass the .pfx file keytool bombs saying

```
Input not an X.509 certificate.
```

How can I fix this, is there a way to convert the .pfx into a .pem certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so easily using the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -out certificate.cer -nodes
```

You can also name the output certificate `certificate.pem` if you wish. PEM certificates can usually have any of the following extentions: `.pem`, `.crt`, `.cer`, and `.key`